# Find asymptotes of $(2x)/(x-1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

What are the asymptotes of $$\frac{2x}{(x-1)^2}$$ ? 
I have problems already on domain.

Comment: Regarding domain: you can't divide by zero.

Answer (score 2):

Asymptote: $\displaystyle{y = ax + b}$.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[{2x \over \left(x - 1\right)^{2}} - ax - b\right] = 0\,,
\quad
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\left\{x\left[{2 \over \left(x - 1\right)^{2}} - a - {b \over x}\right]\right\}
=0
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\left[{2 \over \left(x - 1\right)^{2}} - a - {b \over x}\right] = 0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
a = 0
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\left[{2x \over \left(x - 1\right)^{2}} - b\right] = 0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
b = 0
$$

$$
\mbox{Asymptote:}\quad y = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

So $f(x)=\frac{2x}{(x-1)^2}$. Here you horizontal asymptote will be found by taking the lim as x $\rightarrow\infty$, which should be $0$. And your veritval asymptotes will be where the denominator vanishes (i.e when $ (x-1)^2=0$).

Comment: how do you calculate m? i cant do [(2x)/(x−1)2 ] / x i know its very basic

Comment: Where is this "m" coming from??

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of asymptotes you will need to check for:

1. $\textbf{Vertical asymptotes}$: These are the $x$-values at which the denominator evaluates to zero. In your case, the vertical asymptote is at $x=1$.
2. $\textbf{Horizontal asymptotes}$: If you rational function is proper, i.e the degree of the numerator is lower than the degree of the denominator, then the horizontal asymptote will be at $y=0$. Notice,that your rational function is $\textbf{not}$ proper.

To find the horizontal asymptote of a rational function which is not proper, as is the case here, you need to use polynomial long division, i.e divide $(x-1)^2$ by $x$. The quotient is a horizontal asymptote if it is a constant.

3. $\textbf{Oblique Asymptote}$: If your quotient is a linear function, i.e., of the form $ax+b$, then you have an oblique asymptote.

Comment: your definition for horizontal ansymptote is backwards. You want your numerator to have a degree lower than or equal to the denominator. If the degree of the numerator is lower than it's at $y=0$, if the degrees are equal it will be at the line $y=k$ where $k$ is the ratio of the leading coefficients of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the mistake!